# different startsite for IOS and change menu

Tags: mobile, iphone, homepage

I have a homesite and a second site. They are displayed to normal browsers.

But I would like to show IOS and mobile devices the second site as homesite and hide the normal homesite.

How can I do this?

Joerg

Answer (score 1):

If the url's for both site is different, You can simply check if site is being viewed from mobile or not and than you can redirect to your second site if it is mobile...

Here is one of code who detects whether it is mobile or not...

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

You can use such code detect mobile browser agent and put it on first site and if mobile is detected redirect them to second site..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) which has User Agent detection and can serve a different theme or redirect to a mobile site based on what browser a visitor is using.

WordPress has some more basic User Agent detection built in. You can target the iPhone with the `is_iphone` function. So for example you could add something like this to your themes `header.php`:

```
<?php global $is_iphone; if($is_iphone) { ?>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://MobileSite.com/">
<?php } ?>
```

Here's a list of all the [browser detection functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Browser_Detection_Booleans) from the WordPress Codex.

Comment: There aren't conditional functions for this. These are global variables. Instead of `is_iphone()` you have to use `global $is_iphone; if($is_iphone)`

Comment: Ahh,thanks. I hadn't tested it, I've updated my answer.